# Build tree structure from the records

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I query database for records in structure as follows

> ID | Term | ParentID

In C# code I have following class

```
public class Tree
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public IList<Tree> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
```

Query returns 5 000 000 records.

I need to build tree of Tree items and populate it.

First at all, I select all items where `ParentID` is null, and then for every element search parent (if parent doesn't exist I build parent of the parent and so on) and build tree using recursion.

I'm not happy with my algorithm because It takes more than 5 minutes.

Please, let me some advice how to do that, what to use and so on.

This is how the code is now implemented:

```
private string Handle2(List<Tree> originalTree)
{            
    IList<Tree> newTree = new List<TreeTest.Models.Tree>();
    IList<Tree> treeWithoutParents = originalTree.Where(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ParentID)).OrderBy(x => x.Term).ToList();

    foreach(Tree item in treeWithoutParents)
    {
        Tree newItem = new Tree { Id = item.ID, Term = item.Term, ParentId = item.ParentID, Level = 0 };
        newTree.Add(newItem);

        InsertChilds(newItem, originalTree, 0);
    }

    return "output";
}

private void InsertChilds(Tree item, List<Tree> origTree, int level)
{
    ++level;
    IList<Tree> childItems = origTree.Where(x => x.ParentID == item.Id).ToList();
    origTree.RemoveAll(x => x.ParentID == item.Id);

    foreach (Tree i in childItems)
    {
        origTree.Remove(i);
    }

    foreach (Tree tItem in childItems)
    {
        if (item.ChildTree == null)
        {
            item.ChildTree = new List<TreeTest.Models.Tree>();
        }

        Tree itemToAdd = new Tree { Id = tItem.ID, Term = tItem.Term, ParentId = tItem.ParentID, Level = level };
        this.InsertChilds(itemToAdd, origTree, level);

        item.ChildTree.Add(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a map (C# [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) of ID (`string`, although I'm curious why that isn't `int`) to node (`Tree` object) to store your tree nodes.

This would allow you to get the node corresponding to an ID with expected O(1) complexity, rather than your current O(n) complexity.

Beyond that, I suggest you rethink your approach a bit - try to write code which involves you only going through the input data once, just use a single Dictionary - if the parent doesn't exist yet, you could just create a filler-item for the parent, which has its members populated only when you get to that item.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary (hash table) to make this faster. Here is my algorithm in pseudocode:

```
- create a dictionary mapping ID to IList<Tree> // mapping a node to its children
- create Queue<string,string> of IDs //item (3,5) in the queue corresponds to a node with ID=3 that has a parent with ID=5
- initialize the queue with all the codes with no parent
    - List<Tree> withoutParent = dictionary[null]
    - for each item in withoutParent:
        - add (item.Id, null) to the queue
- while queue is not empty:
    - (id,pid) = delete an item from the queue
    - make a new node t
        - t.Id = id
        - t.parentId = pid
    - t.ChildItems = dictionary[id]
    - for each child in t.ChildItems:
        - add (child.Id, id) to the queue
```

Answer (score 0):

1. is the column ID a unique identifier. If it is then you can  try the following. Instead of using a List, use a Set or a hashmap. This is because if a parent has too many child, lookup in a list can slow down your operations. If you use a Set, you can do a quick lookup and you can also do a quick addition of your elements.
2. Also, can you check how much time an order by clause will take . This might really help you speed up your process. If ID is a clustered index, you will get a fast sort by(as the data is already sorted) , else your query will still use the same index
3. When a parent does not exist , you are creating a parent of a parent. I would try to avoid that. What you can do is in case a child's parent  does not exist in the tree, add it to a separate list. After you have gone through the original list , make a second pass to find orphaned elements. The advantage is that you do not need to resize your tree every time you create a parent of parent and then find out that the parent was just at the end of the list